# Load view codeigniter with plain text

Tags: model-view-controller, templates, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my website and I was wondering if I could load a view in a view without using PHP. So like a Template Parser, is it possible to run this code:

```
<div>
    <?php $this->load->view('widget'); ?>
</div>
```

with plain text like:

```
<div>
    {loadview:widget}
</div>
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there's nothing built in to Codeigniter that does this. You'll have to look at using a third party [template parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+template+engine) or write your own.

Some suggestions:

- Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ (recommend)
- Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/
- Dwoo: http://dwoo.org/
- Mustache: http://mustache.github.com/ (not full featured, but language indepenent)

With [CI's native template parser](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html), you can assign a variable that contains the content:

```
$data['widget'] = $this->load->view('widget', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

The third param as `TRUE` buffers the output so you can use it in a variable without it printing. Then in your view:

```
<div>
    {{widget}}
</div>
```

..but currently, CI's parser has very limited capabilities. I'd go with Twig or Smarty.