# CodeIgniter modular CMS with templates

Tags: templates, codeigniter, content-management-system, modular

You all probably think "oh my god another guy who wants to create a CMS", 
but I really need your help!
I want to create an own CMS with modules and templates.
I've already installed Modular Extensions, but now I'm struggling with the templates.
I just don't know how to build that exactly.

I know the template library Smarty and the one from Phil.

Could you guys help me a bit how to create this, I want to build this something like PyroCMS or Ionize, but then in the root: application/system/templates
Just so I can build templates in the future for my CMS and that i can use tags like {cms.navigation} and {cms.page.title} or something

My structure

```
application
system
templates
 - css
 - img
 - js
 - header.php
 - home.php
 - footer.php

application/modules
- blog
 - controllers
 - models
 - views
 - blog_routes.php
- guestbook
- pages
- etc
- etc
```

Comment: You sound like you're off to a decent start, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly how to use or even what engine to use for a template system..
So I want to use a seperate directory for templates, but how do I create a template system?

Comment: Don't create one, use an existing one. See my answer from earlier this morning for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669776/load-view-codeigniter-with-plain-text/9671521#9671521 I'm using Twig and CI with great success. I've also used Smarty and CI. I guarantee if you put a couple hours into it, you'll get it figured out to the point where you'll have more specific questions.

Comment: Basically, you'll end up abandoning `$this->load->view()` for the template engines loader, or your own abstracted version of it.

Comment: yes okay, but for example, I create my layout and I want to replace curly brackets to modules, how do I create that? so {module:slider} has to be replaced with the Slider module, or {categories:5} has to be replaced with a list with 5 last categories..

Comment: Trust me when I say writing a proper parser is a lot of work, there are many intricacies involved. Use an existing one. Smarty has a pretty extensible syntax, good docs, and a large community - might want to start there. Yes, you can do simple `str_replace()` but you will soon learn it's limits and caveats.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found Friendly template engine for CI.  It works with MVC or HMVC fine.  It's certainly not as well documented or popular as some that Wesley Murch mentioned in his other post, but it's light and fast.  It can be installed via Spark or without. There are 3 ways to display the html coming out of your controllers...

A nifty ways to use it:

```
$this->template->main_content = $this->load->view('dashboard/tables/faq_pages_list', $info_array, true);
```

inside your template:

```
echo $this->template->main_content;
```

Friendly template also allows you to use the { curly brackets } if you load and use CI's native parser.

https://github.com/segersjens/CodeIgniter-Template-Library